# Finding Index from Vector/Matrix or Dataframe in R

Tags: r, indexing

I have data in R as follow:

```
data <- c(1,12,22,0,8,1,0,0)
```

Is there any way to index the data to find the index for element that is greater than 0? So the result will be:

```
1 2 3 5 6
```

I tried to use as.factor(data), but it will take several more step to get the result that I aim for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `which` on a logical `vector`

```
which(data >0)
#[1] 1 2 3 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `seq_along` (but not as straightforward as the `which` method by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65242060/12158757))

```
> seq_along(data)[data>0]
[1] 1 2 3 5 6
```